# How can I flush the output of the print function?

Tags: python, printing, flush, output-buffering

How do I force Python's `print` function to flush the buffered output to the screen?

---

<sub>**See also:** [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705) if the goal is to change the buffering behaviour generally. This question is about explicitly flushing output after a specific `print` call, even though output is still being buffered.</sub>

<sub>**For duplicate closers:** if a beginner is asking a question about trying to make output appear immediately while not using a newline at the end, **please instead use** [Why doesn't print output show up immediately in the terminal when there is no newline at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897335) to close the question. The current question isn't good enough because the person asking will likely **not have a concept** of buffering or flushing; the other question is intended to explain those concepts first, whereas this question is about the technical details.</sub>

Comment: `python -u <script.py>` worked (forced flushed, no buffering) for me without having to modify script.

Comment: Note that the behavior is famously broken within IDEs.  For example, PyCharm works correctly in the debug console, but not in the run console.   You may need to isolate that the problem exists in a regular terminal.

Answer (score 1890, accepted):

In Python 3, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) can take an optional `flush` argument:

```
print("Hello, World!", flush=True)
```

In Python 2, after calling `print`, do:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

By default, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) prints to [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) (see the documentation for more about [file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)).

Comment: if I do `sys.stdout.flush()` can I avoid putting the flush key word? I have many prints in my file and don't want to change them + I want my files to always flush and I don't want to write it ever. Just always flush is what I want. Will putting `sys.stdout.flush()` that at the top be enough? (I am using python 3 and above)

Comment: No, you would need to do `sys.stdout.flush()` (or use `print(..., flush=True)` in Python 3) every time you call `print`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230780/2328207) for another solution that might work for you.

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()` works with Python 3 too.

Comment: is there a command one can give to the command line to force flush?

Comment: btw does `import sys
sys.stdout.flush()` work for python3 still? I'd rather not have to modify my entire scripts to force flush.

Comment: `python -u <script.py>` worked for me without having to modify script.

Comment: probably very late, but if you want your prints to always flush like @Charlie Parker, you could use `print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)`

Comment: isn't `python -u <script.py>` best since it doesn't need you to change your code?

Comment: python v3.3 supports `print(..., flush=True)`

Comment: Sometimes python 3.8.3 on my Mac, flush=True does nothing, when the next message is a logger. I have to add sys.stdout.flush()

Answer (score 442):

You can change the flushing behavior using the `-u` command line flag, e.g. `python -u script.py`.

> -u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
> see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'

Here is the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: If you're running it on Linux/Unix platform, you can add the `-u` in the interpreter command line (first line of the script file), so change the first line from (something like) `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python3 -u` - now when you run your script (e.g. `./my_script.py`) the `-u` will always be added for you

Comment: `-u` works as expected (Y)

Comment: @JamesStevens, caution specifying flags in shebang, behavior of 2+ arguments is not well defined across platforms

Answer (score 342):

Since Python 3.3, you can force the normal `print()` function to flush without the need to use `sys.stdout.flush()`; just set the "flush" keyword argument to true.  From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print):

> **print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)**
>
> Print objects to the stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end.
>
> The file argument must be an object with a write(string) method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used. **Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the flush keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.**

Comment: if I do `sys.stdout.flush()` can I avoid putting the flush key word? I have many prints in my file and don't want to change them + I want my files to always flush and I don't want to write it ever. Just always flush is what I want. Will putting `sys.stdout.flush()` that at the top be enough? (I am using python 3 and above)

Comment: btw does `import sys
sys.stdout.flush()` work for python3 still? I'd rather not have to modify my entire scripts to force flush.

Answer (score 275):

> ## How to flush output of Python print?

I suggest five ways of doing this:

- In Python 3, call `print(..., flush=True)` (the flush argument is not available in Python 2's print function, and there is no analogue for the print statement).
- Call `file.flush()` on the output file (we can wrap python 2's print function to do this), for example, `sys.stdout`
- apply this to every print function call in the module with a partial function,
  `print = partial(print, flush=True)` applied to the module global.
- apply this to the process with a flag (`-u`) passed to the interpreter command
- apply this to every python process in your environment with `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE` (and unset the variable to undo this).

### Python 3.3+

Using Python 3.3 or higher, you can just provide `flush=True` as a keyword argument to the `print` function:

```
print('foo', flush=True)
```

### Python 2 (or < 3.3)

They did not backport the `flush` argument to Python 2.7 So if you're using Python 2 (or less than 3.3), and want code that's compatible with both 2 and 3, may I suggest the following compatibility code. (Note the `__future__` import must be at/very "near the [top of your module](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements)"):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 3):
    old_print = print
    def print(*args, **kwargs):
        flush = kwargs.pop('flush', False)
        old_print(*args, **kwargs)
        if flush:
            file = kwargs.get('file', sys.stdout)
            # Why might file=None? IDK, but it works for print(i, file=None)
            file.flush() if file is not None else sys.stdout.flush()
```

The above compatibility code will cover most uses, but for a much more thorough treatment, [see the `six` module](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/3deee854df8a5f1cc04dd721c18dee2128584f8c/six.py?at=default#six.py-721).

Alternatively, you can just call `file.flush()` after printing, for example, with the print statement in Python 2:

```
import sys
print 'delayed output'
sys.stdout.flush()
```

### Changing the default in one module to `flush=True`

You can change the default for the print function by using functools.partial on the global scope of a module:

```
import functools
print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)
```

if you look at our new partial function, at least in Python 3:

```
>>> print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)
>>> print
functools.partial(<built-in function print>, flush=True)
```

We can see it works just like normal:

```
>>> print('foo')
foo
```

And we can actually override the new default:

```
>>> print('foo', flush=False)
foo
```

Note again, this only changes the current global scope, because the print name on the current global scope will overshadow the builtin `print` function (or unreference the compatibility function, if using one in Python 2, in that current global scope).

If you want to do this inside a function instead of on a module's global scope, you should give it a different name, e.g.:

```
def foo():
    printf = functools.partial(print, flush=True)
    printf('print stuff like this')
```

If you declare it a global in a function, you're changing it on the module's global namespace, so you should just put it in the global namespace, unless that specific behavior is exactly what you want.

### Changing the default for the process

I think the best option here is to use the `-u` flag to get unbuffered output.

```
$ python -u script.py
```

or

```
$ python -um package.module
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u):

> Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
>
> Note that there is internal buffering in file.readlines() and File Objects (for line in sys.stdin) which is not influenced by this option. To work around this, you will want to use file.readline() inside a while 1: loop.

### Changing the default for the shell operating environment

You can get this behavior for all python processes in the environment or environments that inherit from the environment if you set the environment variable to a nonempty string:

e.g., in Linux or OSX:

```
$ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
```

or Windows:

```
C:\SET PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED):

> **PYTHONUNBUFFERED**
>
> If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent to specifying the -u option.

---

### Addendum

Here's the help on the print function from Python 2.7.12 - note that there is *no* `flush` argument:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> help(print)
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
    
    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

Comment: For the curious migrating from lower Python versions: the `__future__` version doesn't include `flush` because "the flush argument was added in Python 3.3 (after print() was backported to 2.7 via a future import)" https://bugs.python.org/issue28458

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Provides workarounds and plenty of information.

Comment: if I do `sys.stdout.flush()` can I avoid putting the flush key word? I have many prints in my file and don't want to change them + I want my files to always flush and I don't want to write it ever. Just always flush is what I want. Will putting `sys.stdout.flush()` that at the top be enough? (I am using python 3 and above)

Comment: No, but you can do something like `import functools; 
 print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)` at the top of your module (e.g. after the imports) and even assign it to the name `print` at `builtins.print` for process-wide applicability.

Comment: like `import functools;   print2 = functools.partial(print, flush=True); builtins.print=print2`? @AaronHall

Comment: btw does `import sys
sys.stdout.flush()` work for python3 still? I'd rather not have to modify my entire scripts to force flush.

Answer (score 72):

Also, as suggested in [this blog post](http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.com/2009/10/python-tips-and-tricks-flushing-stdout.html), one can reopen `sys.stdout` in unbuffered mode:

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

Each `stdout.write` and `print` operation will be automatically flushed afterwards.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 in python 2.7 this gives me `UnsupportedOperation: IOStream has no fileno.`

Comment: Whoops, Python 3 found out. It won't let me execute this piece of code!

Comment: I'm confused by this idiom.  After you do this, aren't there now two File-like objects (the original sys.stdout and the new sys.stdout) that both think they "own" the fileno?  That's bad, right?

Comment: if you check de docs, buffering=0 only works in binary mode. ```buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer.```

Answer (score 70):

With Python 3.x the `print()` function has been extended:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

So, you can just do:

```
print("Visiting toilet", flush=True)
```

---

[Python Docs Entry](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)

Comment: How is it different from [Eugene Sajine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function/23142556#23142556)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen *this* answer has potty humor, the other does not.

Answer (score 40):

Using the `-u` command-line switch works, but it is a little bit clumsy. It would mean that the program would potentially behave incorrectly if the user invoked the script without the `-u` option.  I usually use a custom `stdout`, like this:

```
class flushfile:
  def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f

  def write(self, x):
    self.f.write(x)
    self.f.flush()

import sys
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
```

... Now all your `print` calls (which use `sys.stdout` implicitly), will be automatically `flush`ed.

Comment: I recommend not inheriting from file and then delegating to stdout by adding. `def __getattr__(self,name): return object.__getattribute__(self.f, name)`

Comment: Without the changes suggested by the comment by @diedthreetimes, I get "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Answer (score 20):

Use an unbuffered file:

```
f = open('xyz.log', 'a', 0)
```

*Or*

```
sys.stdout = open('out.log', 'a', 0)
```

Comment: He does not want ot create an unbuffered file; he wants to make the existing stdout (redirected to the console, the terminal or whatever: this must not be changed) unbuffered.

Answer (score 18):

In Python 3 you can overwrite the *print* function with the default set to `flush = True`

```py
def print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=True):
    __builtins__.print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

Comment: this answer seems a little light given all the other high quality responses. you may want to add a little more to it.

Answer (score 16):

[Dan's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function/231216#231216) doesn't quite work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class flushfile(file):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()

import sys
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)

print "foo"
```

The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./passpersist.py", line 12, in <module>
    print "foo"
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I believe the problem is that it inherits from the file class, which actually isn't necessary. According to the documentation for sys.stdout:

> stdout and stderr needn’t be built-in
> file objects: any object is acceptable
> as long as it has a write() method
> that takes a string argument.

so changing

```
class flushfile(file):
```

to

```
class flushfile(object):
```

makes it work just fine.

Comment: No vote because this IS @Dan's solution... (You should rather comment Dan's post instead of copying his solution)

Answer (score 12):

Here is my version, which provides writelines() and fileno(), too:

```
class FlushFile(object):
    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.fd = fd

    def write(self, x):
        ret = self.fd.write(x)
        self.fd.flush()
        return ret

    def writelines(self, lines):
        ret = self.writelines(lines)
        self.fd.flush()
        return ret

    def flush(self):
        return self.fd.flush

    def close(self):
        return self.fd.close()

    def fileno(self):
        return self.fd.fileno()
```

Comment: Superior solution. And it works. Tested on Python 3.4.0.  With the other versions, which derive from `file`, I get an error.  There is no `file` class.

Answer (score 8):

I did it like this in Python 3.4:

```
'''To write to screen in real-time'''
message = lambda x: print(x, flush=True, end="")
message('I am flushing out now...')
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how is it different from [Eugene Sajine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function/23142556#23142556)?

Answer (score 5):

I first struggled to understand how the flush option was working. I wanted to do a 'loading display' and here is the solution I found:

```
for i in range(100000):
    print('{:s}\r'.format(''), end='', flush=True)
    print('Loading index: {:d}/100000'.format(i+1), end='')
```

The first line flushes the previous print and the second line prints a new updated message. I don't know if an one-line syntax exists here.

Answer (score 0):

In python3, as mentioned above, setting `print(..., flush=True)` is great, but for a given application, you likely would prefer to flush every print:

```py
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    __builtins__.print(*args, flush=True, **kwargs)
```